# Cannot invoke 'dataTask' with an argument list of type (with: NSMutableRequest, ...)

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask, nsurlsessionconfiguration

[image]

```
func performGetRequest(_ targetURL: URL!, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ HTTPStatusCode: Int, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: targetURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            completion(data, (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error)
        })
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

Here I am trying a demo from appCoda to integrate YouTube API. But not able to move further because of this method error :

Cannot invoke 'dataTask' with an argument list of type '(with: NSMutableURLRequest, completionHandler:(Data?, URLResponse..)'

Comment: yes, I have edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is unclear, what do you want to accomplish and what errors are you encountering? Please see the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: `let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: targetURL)` use `URLRequest` instead of `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Comment: sorry I'm new to swift. Not getting exactly what to ask with.. If you can help please.

Comment: NSStuff: Old Objective-C one. Prefers Swift Type (whenever there is a class prefixed with NS, check if there isn't the Swift equivalent witouth, and without "Mutable" also). The `dataTask` doesn't know a method `(with:` where the first param is of class NSMutableURLRequest, that's why the compiler was yelling at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
func performGetRequest(_ targetURL: URL!, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ HTTPStatusCode: Int, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: targetURL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            completion(data, (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error)
        })
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use URLRequest instead of NSMutableURLRequest:

```
public func getData(withApiEndpoint apiURL: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Swift.Void) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: apiURL)!)
        for (key, value) in self.getDefaultHeaders() {
            request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }

        request.httpMethod = String.kGet

        if self.networkSession == nil {
            self.networkSession = URLSession(configuration: getSharedConfiguration(self.isIncognito))
        }
        self.networkDataTask = self.networkSession?.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                debugPrint(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            completionHandler(data, response, error)
        }
        self.networkDataTask?.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use URLRequest  inseatd of  NSMutableURLRequest

```
func performGetRequest(_ targetURL: URL!, completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?, _ HTTPStatusCode: Int, _ error: NSError?) -> Void) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: targetURL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)


        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                completion(data, (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode, error)
            })
        } as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)

        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Hi, this has been already defined in the above comments. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: This is resulting in EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP,subcode=0x0) in last line  as! (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)

Comment: Minute I will check for you